# R Shiny - uploading multiple csv works locally but not on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have produced an app that allows the user to upload multiple csv files.

These csvs are then 'rbind' together, 'read.csv' and have a column added to the df which is the filename.

The df is then processed to produce various plots which are downloadable.  This works perfectly locally but not when deployed. I've replicated the error with the code below:

Warning in file(file, "rt") :cannot open file '*.csv': No such file or directory

Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection

UI:

```
    dashboardPage( skin = "black",
   dashboardHeader(title = "myApp"),
   dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE,
   sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Home", tabName = "dashboard1", icon = icon("home", lib = 
  "glyphicon"))
    ) 
    ),
   dashboardBody(
     tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
      .main-header .logo {
                          font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
                          font-weight: bold;
                          font-size: 24px;
                          }
                          '))),

tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "dashboard1",
          fileInput("file1",
                    label="Input files:",
                    multiple = TRUE),
          downloadButton('plot.pdf', 'Download Data')
  )
  )

)
)
```

Server:

```
     library(shiny)
     library(shinydashboard)

     #server start
     function(input, output) {

       testinput<- reactive({
if(is.null(input$file1))
  return ()
else 
{
  nfiles = nrow(input$file1) 
  csv = list()
  for (i in 1 : nfiles)
  {

    csv[[i]] = read.csv(input$file1$datapath[i])

  }

  csv_names <- input$file1[['name']]
  mydata <- do.call(rbind, lapply(csv_names, function(x) cbind(read.csv(x), name=strsplit(x,'\\.')[[1]][1])))
  View(mydata)
    }
   })

     output$plot.pdf <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
     "plot.pdf"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      withProgress(message = 'Your file is downloading',
               detail = 'This may take a minute or two...', value = 0, {
                 for (i in 1:10) {
                   incProgress(1/10)
                   Sys.sleep(0.5)}

                 pdf(file)
                 print(testinput())
                 dev.off()

               })
 }

 )


   }
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I have searched tons of SO and other forums and I'm really stuck.

Please help

Comment: Please provide full `ui` and `server` code, not just some part of it.

Comment: @JimChen sorry, I have now added script that replicates my issue - I'm new to R so apologies if this is a basic question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `csv_names <- input$file1[['name']]` in your `server`, this only return the file name, not file path, so when you use `read.csv` to read the csv file, the error occured.

The following should work fine.

### ui

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


dashboardPage( skin = "black",
               dashboardHeader(title = "myApp"),
               dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE,
                                sidebarMenu(
                                  menuItem("Home", tabName = "dashboard1", icon = icon("home", lib = 
                                                                                         "glyphicon"))
                                ) 
               ),
               dashboardBody(
                 tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
      .main-header .logo {
                          font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
                          font-weight: bold;
                          font-size: 24px;
                          }
                          '))),

                 tabItems(
                   tabItem(tabName = "dashboard1",
                           fileInput("file1",
                                     label="Input files:",
                                     multiple = TRUE),
                           downloadButton('plot.pdf', 'Download Data')
                   )
                 )

               )
)
```

### server

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

#server start
function(input, output) {

  testinput<- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$file1))
      return ()
    else 
    {
      nfiles = nrow(input$file1) 
      csv = list()
      for (i in 1 : nfiles)
      {

        csv[[i]] = read.csv(input$file1$datapath[i])

      }

      csv_names <- input$file1$datapath
      mydata <- do.call(rbind, lapply(csv_names, function(x) cbind(read.csv(x), name=strsplit(basename(x),'\\.')[[1]][1])))
      mydata
    }
  })

  output$plot.pdf <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "plot.pdf"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      withProgress(message = 'Your file is downloading',
                   detail = 'This may take a minute or two...', value = 0, {
                     for (i in 1:10) {
                       incProgress(1/10)
                       Sys.sleep(0.5)}

                     pdf(file)
                     plot(testinput()[,1])
                     dev.off()

                   })
    }        
  )   
}
```

Comment: This partially works however the filename isn't correct - any ideas?

Comment: You mean which part of the code ? If you want to extract file name from path , you can use `basename` function

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(csv_names, function(x) cbind(read.csv(x), name=strsplit(basename(x),'\\.')[[1]][1])))` - this doesn't bind the name of the file *.csv, that's the last thing I need

Comment: It seems `fileInput` function will automatically turn your uploaded file name into a number sequence in the temp file, you can try to add the name you want in the file you upload, not discriminate by file name.

Comment: cheers for all the help with this - got a work around via new df with `input$file1&name` and then merging the two df together